# Why didn't Thor's artificial eye melt while forging Stormbreaker?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, during the scene at Nidavellir, Thor holds the forge's iris mechanism open so that the light of the star heats up the metal.

My question is, how come Thor's artificial right eye didn't melt?

It is understandable to accept that Thor is a Norse god, with a lot of All-Father strength, but that eye doesn't hold any Asgardian material in it.

Comment: But it's entirely surrounded by Thor's body/tissues, which survived intact.

Answer (score 5):

It has never been elaborated on exactly what that eye was made of, and whether it has additional features, e.g. stimulating cell regrowth (cells which are in and of themselves Asgardian).

It's also unclear whether Thor's All-Father strength is physically applied to his biological material, or rather applied to his body in general. Because if you assume that it's only applied to Thor's biological material, are you then also expecting the clothes he wears (or even the food in his stomach) to be disintegrated as well?

There's no real information on this eye, nor on Thor's All-Father strength, to draw any real conclusion here.

---

In my opinion, Thor enduring the focused energy of a star is insanely out of scope of any real-world consideration. Any being able to withstand that would be ridiculously unstoppable, even more so than Thor is already represented in the MCU. Thor can get wounded from combat, and no opponent we've seen Thor battle is going to come close to matching the focused energy coming from a star.

Comment: It’s insanely out of scope in universe as well. My suspension of disbelief really fell off the wagen during that scene.

Comment: Really? After Bi - frost, talking trees and racoons, Thor's first Lazarus in Brannagh's original and EVERYTHING we have seen up until Nidavellir, this is where your suspension of disbelief reaches its limit?